# Delete Existing Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I used the following JavaScript to create a pop-up window on the website and for it to show up only once. Now, my client wants a new promotion and I am trying to delete existing cookies and make it pop-up again (so that people who already visited the website, see the pop-up window again, only once like before).  Here is the current code:

```
<!--
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
 var curCookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
   ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
   ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
   ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
   ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
 document.cookie = curCookie;
}

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
 var curCookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
   ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
   ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
   ((secure) ? "; secure" : "") +
    ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") ;
 document.cookie = curCookie;
}


function getCookie(name) {
 var dc = document.cookie;
 var prefix = name + "=";
 var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
 if (begin == -1) {
  begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
  if (begin != 0) return null;
 } else
  begin += 2;
 var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
 if (end == -1)
  end = dc.length;
 return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
function pop()
{
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').reveal();
});
}
var seen = getCookie("seen");
if (!seen) {
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(now.getTime() + 360000 * 1000);
setCookie("seen", 1, now);
pop();
}
//-->
```

I tried the following to reset the cookies

```
<!--
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
 var curCookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
   ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
   ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
   ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
   ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
 document.cookie = curCookie;
}

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
 var curCookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
   ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
   ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
   ((secure) ? "; secure" : "") +
   **";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";**
 document.cookie = curCookie;
}


function getCookie(name) {
 var dc = document.cookie;
 var prefix = name + "=";
 var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
 if (begin == -1) {
  begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
  if (begin != 0) return null;
 } else
  begin += 2;
 var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
 if (end == -1)
  end = dc.length;
 return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
function pop()
{
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').reveal();
});
}
var seen = getCookie("seen");
if (!seen) {
var now = new Date();
now.setTime(now.getTime() + 1 * 1000);
setCookie("seen", 1, now);
pop();
}
//-->
```

It's not working. I'm new to JavaScript and would appreciate your help!

Comment: I need to delete the existing ones, so that people who already visited the website, see the pop-up window again, but then save it again, so it doesn't pop-up every time.

Comment: Try using `localStorage` instead? Now has solid support, conceptually easier, and also, far easier to figure out where errors are going.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a nice mess so, if I have understood well, this code should do the job:

```
// on document ready
$(function(){

    // check for the old cookie and delete it
    if( Cookies.Check('seen') ) Cookies.Set('seen', '', -1); // delete the cookie if it exists

    // now work with a new one with other name
    if( !Cookies.Check('newmodal') ){ // if the cookie doesn't exist we show the modal and set the cookie
        $('#myModal').reveal();
        Cookies.Set('newmodal', 'true', 365); // days, if you need to use minutes see the method below
    } // there is no `else` here, if the cookie exists nothing happens
});



/**
 * Object with methods to manage cookies
 * @type Object
 */
var Cookies = {

    /**
     * Checks if a cookie exists
     * @param {String} name
     * @return Boolean
     */
    Check: function (name) {
        return !!this.Get(name);
    },

    /**
     * Gets a cookie value or returns false
     * @param {String} name
     * @return String|Boolean
     */
    Get: function (name) {
        var n, ca, c;
        n = name + "=";
        ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            c = ca[i].trim();
            if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) return c.substring(name.length + 1, c.length);
        }
        return false;
    },

    /**
     * Sets a cookie
     * @param {String} name
     * @param {String} value
     * @param {Number} [expire]
     * @param {Object} [options]
     * @return Boolean|void
     */
    Set: function (name, value, expire, options) {
        var d = new Date(), expires;
        var defaults = { expire_in: 'days', path: '/' };
        if (typeof options !== "undefined") $.extend(true, defaults, options);
        if (expire !== undefined && expire !== null) {
            if (defaults.expire_in == 'days') d.setDate(d.getDate() + expire);
            else if (defaults.expire_in == 'minutes') d.setDate(d.getTime() + expire * 1000);
            else {
                throw new JUtils.EX('expire_in configuration is not valid');
            }
            expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        }
        else expires = expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; " + expires + '; path=' + defaults.path;
        return true;
    }

};
```

Comment: kmsdev, thank you for your help! It works if I clear existing cookies manually though my browser, but the code itself doesn't clear out the existing cookies. My problem is that cookies were saved before, so everybody who visited the website before, doesn't see the new pop up. I need to re-set that, so that they see the new pop-up one more time.

Comment: You are welcome. You can just delete the old cookie and set a new one with other name. I updated my answer.

Comment: I am glad. Please check the answer as valid if it resolved the issue 